# How to set a public var in a popup window?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, variables, window, public

I am trying to set a variable in a titlewindow pupup and use it in a script section. The variable is not being set and I don't know why.

Here is my Main.mxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" creationComplete="application1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

        protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            var test:TestWindow = TestWindow(PopUpManager.createPopUp(this,TestWindow,true));
            PopUpManager.centerPopUp(test);
            test.testText = 'test 2';
            test.bol = true;
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
</s:Application>
```

Here is my titleWindow file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:TitleWindow xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="400" height="300"
           close="PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);" creationComplete="titlewindow1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

        [Bindable] public var testText:String = 'test 1';
        public var bol:Boolean = false;

        protected function titlewindow1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            if(bol){
                trace('Boolean is true');
            }
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<s:Label text='{testText}'/>
</s:TitleWindow>
```

The problem is the label does change from 'test 1' to 'test 2' but the bol variable will not be set, why is that?

Answer (score 0):

The `creationComplete` event fires when your TitleWindow has been completely created and only fires once (see [component lifecycle](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ascomponents_advanced_2.html)).

In your case this happens in your Main.mxml file when you add the pop up with `PopUpManager.centerPopUp(test);`.  `bol` is getting updated, you're just not seeing that from a trace statement because the `creationComplete` event has already fired.

If you want to to change the value for `bol` with your current setup you'll need to do that prior to opening the pop up.

In general I feel that a better way of doing this would be by using [getters and setters](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/04_OO_Programming_07.html#129629) and data binding (or Flex's invalidation methods which is described in that first link).

Note: these links provided are for Flex 3 but so far as I know all this holds true in Flex 4.

Answer (score 0):

NoobsArePeople2 is 100% correct about what's going on with the lifecycle. A quick and dirty workaround for this is to use PopUpManager.addPopUp() instead of createPopUp():

```
var test:TestWindow = new TestWindow();
test.testText = 'test 2';
test.bol = true;
PopUpManager.addPopUp(test, this, true);
PopUpManager.centerPopUp(test);
```

This should allow you to set the values on TestWindow before it actually gets initialized.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/managers/PopUpManager.html